# (index) file is empty for inline js in DevTools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have some Razor application that builds up a page. I'm trying to debug some code in it but `(index)` file is empty. When I put `debugger` keyword it stops as expected, I can see call-stack, variables but there is no code even if I click on stack frame for my code in this generated file. Can I see the code in DevTools to debug it without changing the code?

[image]